# MongoDb SearchQuery Issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database and a table user. when i perform below code i got output as below.

```
$searchQuery = array('userID' => '2');
$collection = $db->mydatabase->users;
$cursor = $collection->find()->limit(2);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  '_id' =>
  class MongoId#8 (1) {
    public $$id =>
    string(24) "56c8216d7f8b9a0e148b4567"
  }
  'userID' =>
  int(7)
  'lastTimeOnline' =>
  string(19) "2016-02-20 01:48:53"
  'displayName' =>
  string(0) ""
}
array(4) {
  '_id' =>
  class MongoId#9 (1) {
    public $$id =>
    string(24) "56c8216d7f8b9a0e148b4568"
  }
  'userID' =>
  int(2)
  'lastTimeOnline' =>
  string(19) "2016-02-20 01:48:53"
  'displayName' =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Now i need to find only those records whose userID is 2, so i change the code as below.

```
$searchQuery = array('userID' => '2');
$collection = $db->mydatabase->users;
$cursor = $collection->find($searchQuery)->limit(2);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

but now the output is blank :-(

I have two doubts.
A) why 2nd code to fetch userId=2 is not working
B)why on both cases var_dump($cursor) is giving below output and why not detail of $doc

```
class MongoCursor#5 (0) {
}
```

Comment: `$cursor = $collection->find(array('userID' => '2'))->limit(2);`

Comment: @Anant same thing and still no result

Comment: What PHP extension are you using? mongo or mongodb? What is the version of your MongoDB server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the userID in database is saved as Integer and your are trying to query using a string parameter, try to change the query array to the following:

```
$searchQuery = array('userID' => 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the userId as an integer and in the query you are using a string due to which you are find nothing so instead of writing 2 like this `'2'` write it like this `2`